# How to quickly check what variables exist from a bunch of vars?

Tags: php

If you have 10 variables that are sometimes set, other times unset, is there a quick way to echo the ones that exist without throwing an exception? These vars come from user input.

I would currently write it as

```
if ($var_1 != NULL) { echo $var_1; }
if ($var_2 != NULL) { echo $var_2; }
if ($var_3 != NULL) { echo $var_3; }
if ($var_other_1 != NULL) { echo $var_other_1 ; }
if ($var_other_2 != NULL) { echo $var_other_2 ; }
```

etc.. But is there a more quicker way?

Comment: If you got "10 variables that are sometimes set, other times unset" in your method body then your code must be messy. If that variables come from user what does it do in your method scope, instead of stay in `$_POST` or `$_GET`? And no. You are not throwing any exception in case of missing variable

Comment: have you looked at `isset($varname)` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[compact](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function will help you

Comment: How so? Seems like vague advice to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

$vararr = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($vararr as $name => $value) {
  echo "{$name}: {$value}<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using variable variables and a list of the variables you want to examine:

```
foreach( array("var_1", "var_2") as $var )
{
    if( isset($$var) )
    {
        echo $$var;
    }
}
```